# iTextSharp PDF Read Error

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have below code

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
{
    for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
    {
        var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageIndex);
        //my other logic goes here
    }
}
```

I'm getting value cannot be null at the line

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
```

I'm not sure why it fails for a few PDFs.  I'm able to read 100s of PDFs but only 4 PDFs, I get this error.

Error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at System.util.collections.HashSet2`1.AddAndCheck(T item)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs.IteratePages(PRIndirectReference rpage)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs.IteratePages(PRIndirectReference rpage)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs.IteratePages(PRIndirectReference rpage)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs.IteratePages(PRIndirectReference rpage)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs.IteratePages(PRIndirectReference rpage)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs.ReadPages()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.PageRefs..ctor(PdfReader reader)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.ReadPages()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.ReadPdf()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(IRandomAccessSource byteSource, Boolean partialRead, Byte[] ownerPassword, X509Certificate certificate, ICipherParameters certificateKey, Boolean closeSourceOnConstructorError)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(String filename)
```

My iTextSharp version is **5.5.7.0**

Comment: Could you please provide file name that throws exceptions ?

Comment: File Name: Bills_080415.pdf... I have many such files processed using this code with the same file naming convention.

Comment: I took a look to exception and I seems happen during `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.ReadPages ` method invocation. Maybe file broken or not well formatted itself.

Comment: I'm able to open them using Acrobat Reader

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: A *"PDF that opens in Adobe Reader"* is not necessary a "valid" PDF. If you don't share the PDFs, your question can't be answered.

Comment: I can't share it due to security reasons... I have already asked the PDF provider to re-generate PDFs in error.

Comment: *I can't share it due to security reasons* - as the issue is related to the specific pdf, there is nothing we can do, merely guesswork is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this topic, I have requested the PDF supplier to regenerate the files in question for me.  They did re-generate and send me and I'm able to process them without any code changes.  It appears that there is something wrong in the PDF content that is not readable by iTextSharp properly.  I still wonder because there was no change in their process and in our process.  It may be a corrupted PDF somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest reason would be that on those 4 PDFs, pdfPath is null instead of a string.  Check for a null value in pdfPath.

Comment: there is no null in the path

Answer (score 0):

The path of the 4 PDFs may be invalid, which means, that there is no PDF file there.

Comment: That would have resulted in a different stack trace.